# Performing multiple ttests and saving the result

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame dat

```
structure(list(tlv = c(1654, 1234, 1832, 1118, 987, 8887, 6089.66666666666, 
7081.38095238095, 8073.09523809523, 9064.80952380951), form1 = c(8887, 
456, 890, 456, 544, 632, 720, 808, 896, 984), form2 = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), form3 = c(1118, 987, 1654, 1234, 1832, 
1118, 987, 1654, 1234, 1832)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I wrote the following code, in order to perform ttest between all variables starting with "form" and tlv. My aim is to save the results as follows

comparison statistic pvalue

```
k=which(grepl("^form",colnames(dat)))
all_t_test = lapply(dat[,k], FUN=function(x) {
            result = t.test(x, dat$tlv)
            data.frame(
              'comparison'=paste(x,collapse="-"),
              'statistic'=result$statistic,
              'p-value'=result$p.value
            )

})
all_t_test =  do.call(rbind,all_t_test)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(all_t_test,"ttest_results.xlsx")
```

It works, statistically. But in the results, in the column "comparison", it gives me the following values

```
NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA
tlv-form1-form2-form3-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA
NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NA
```

rather than

```
form1
form2
form2
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The error was in `comparison= paste(x,collapse="-")`

Comment: HI  @42- could I understand the error? why don't I get the column name?

Comment: Because you passed the values. The column name would be passed as `names(.)` or `colnames(.)`

Comment: @42-   I am trying this, but I get error: 'comparison'=paste(colnames(dat[x], do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "col"),collapse="-"),

Comment: You can't paste all the column names together, which is what your code was almost doing. . You would need to either pass the column names individually to the function from the first  `lapply` argument expression or use the numeric indices to reference them. BTW, You were also missing a closing parenthesis for `colnames(dat[x])`. Notice how both @RonakShah and lunar_props passed the column indices indices to allow reference to both the individual column values and the individual column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by @42- , in `lapply` call `x` are the values in the column and not column name, hence when you do `paste(x,collapse="-")` it pastes the values and not the column names. Try this version -

```
k = grep("^form",colnames(dat)) #No need to use which with grepl, use grep

ttest_results <- lapply(k, FUN=function(x) {
   result = t.test(dat[[x]], dat$tlv)
   data.frame(
     comparison = names(dat)[x],
     statistic = result$statistic,
     p_value = result$p.value
    )
})

ttest_results
#[[1]]
#  comparison statistic p_value
#t      form1     -2.22  0.0404

#[[2]]
#  comparison statistic p_value
#t      form2     -4.13 0.00257

#[[3]]
#  comparison statistic p_value
#t      form3     -2.89  0.0175

do.call(rbind, ttest_results)
#   comparison statistic p_value
#t       form1     -2.22 0.04042
#t1      form2     -4.13 0.00257
#t2      form3     -2.89 0.01745
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
k=which(grepl("^form",colnames(dat)))

ttest_results <- function(x, data){
  result = t.test(data[,x], data$tlv)
  data.frame(
    'comparison'=paste(colnames(data)[x]),
    'statistic'=result$statistic,
    'p-value'=result$p.value
  )
}

all_t_test = lapply(k, FUN=ttest_results, data=dat )
all_t_test =  do.call(rbind,all_t_test)

library(readxl)
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(all_t_test,"ttest_results.xlsx")
```

I changed your code slightly so that you pass the data frame to the function you use lapply with. Now that the data frame is passed to the function you can use the colnames() to extract the variable name and assign it to the 'comparison' column.

Note that the additional argument in lapply passes the data frame to the ttest_results function.

Comment: HI @lunar_props. I get the following error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (data = dat) when I run the line all_t_test = lapply(k, FUN=ttest_results, data=dat )